# How to set width of QTableView columns by model?

Tags: qt, qt4, qtableview, model-view

I'm using `QTableView` with a subclass of `QAbstractTableModel` as its model. By implementing `data()` and `headerdata()` in the subclassed model, it is feasible to control many properties of the table like data, header values, font, and so on.

In my case, I want the model to set the width of each table column. How can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. In your model's data method you can return the role SizeHintRole.
2. A better way would be to subclass `QItemDelegate` and override the method.

See here ([qitemdelegate.html#sizeHint](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html#sizeHint))

**Example -**

```
QSize ItemDelegate::sizeHint( const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    QSize sz;

    if(index.column()==2)
    {
        return QSize(128, option.rect().height());
    }

    return QSize();
}
```

Here I am setting the width of column 2 to 128 pixels and I am filling in the height from the item rectangle held in `QStyleOptionViewItem`.

Comment: I've used this answer for my problem, but I needed to change `return QSize(128, option.rect().height());` to `return QSize(128, option.rect.height());` in order to compile with Qt 4.8.5.