# Initial width of column in QTableView via model

Tags: qt

I have QTableView based on QAbstractTableModel.
In QAbstractTableModel reimplemented method headerData() to set column name and width according to the model. But

```
switch( role )
{
    ...
    case Qt::SizeHintRole       : return QSize( 500, 0 );
    ...
}
```

has no effect. All columns in the table has the same width(). What I should to do to set initial column width properly.

P.S.: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069611/how-to-set-width-of-qtableview-columns-by-model) question was suggested to use delegates to solve the same issue, but I think headerData() should be used.

Comment: I was able to change the header height only.

Comment: try to double click section handler (space between sections) in the header. looks like it should resize to the size hint width in this case

Comment: @vahancho - the same to me

Comment: @Ezee - yes, it works as you say. But what about initial state? May be need to do something with view, to apply width from SizeHintRole?

Comment: I think that's the only usage of horizontal size hint. But you can inherit from `QTableView` and apply sizes from the model in `setModel`.

Comment: @Ezee you can publish your comments as answer, they explains how to use headerData(), and how to set initial sizes for columns in the QTableView;

Comment: Done. Also added some more information there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`QAbstractItemModel` assumes that `Qt::SizeHintRole` can be used in `headerData` method to return supposed size of a header section. Hovewer, usage of this information depend on certain view implementation.

`QHeaderView` uses `Qt::SizeHintRole` to calculate its recommended width if it is horizontal and height if it is vertical.

`QTableView` subscribes at signal `sectionHandleDoubleClicked` of `QHeaderView` and resizes appropriate column based on cells content size and width of header section. The width of header section is the width returned by `headerData` with `Qt::SizeHintRole` if this role is processed otherwise it's calculated based on header section text (content).

If you need to initialize column widths based on `Qt::SizeHintRole` you need to:

- inherit your class from `QTableView`
- reimplement method `setModel` and use and set initial widths of columns based on `Qt::SizeHintRole` using method `QTableView::setColumnWidth`.

Answer (score 6):

After you've populated your model you can set individual policies on columns. This helped me where my table had 4 columns for which I wanted the first two to fill the view and the last two to fit the contents which was fairly narrow and while still having the view fully filled.

```
this->ui->tableView->setModel(model);

ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::Stretch);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have a view problem and your are seeking into the model part of your program.

QTableView class has simple methods:

```cpp
void QTableView::setColumnWidth(int column, int width)
```

and

```cpp
void QTableView::setRowHeight(int row, int height)
```

Comment: Using hedaerData() is more flexible solution, because I don't bind column width to the some column index. Model says to view what data should be displayed for particular column, and what width of the column should be. Moreover, headerData() works properly for header height, but not for width. May be I should tune some properties of the QTableView, or QHeaderVew, to apply sizeHint properly?

Answer (score 1):

Add one or both lines for horizontal and/or vertical header:

Qt 4:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
tableView->verticalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

Qt 5:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
tableView->verticalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

Comment: There is no such `QHeaderView::setResizeMode` ??

Comment: Not a reason to devote if you not found some example in your current library code (Most probably devoted by someone else but not M.Kanan) - I updated the answer to match both Qt 4 and 5